# Porting driver from static to dynamic on Yocto

Tags: kernel, yocto, bitbake

I need to port a Linux device driver that comes from a patch and is compiled statically. I want to have it as a dynamic module.

The driver code for the MAX9286 Camera Deserializer is provided as a patch for the Renesas R-Car ARM device.

https://github.com/CogentEmbedded/meta-rcar/blob/v3.9.0/meta-rcar-gen3-adas/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-renesas/0030-Gen3-LVDS-cameras.patch

I used devtool to prepare the kernel tree with all the applied patches, so I have the final version of the device driver ready as max9286.c.

The recipe builds ok and the .ko is installed into the rootfs, but the kernel has problems loading the driver and shows an error that seems to be related to dynamic linking.

```
[    5.469956] max9286: Unknown symbol of_remove_property (err 0)
```

This is the tree of my driver recipe:

```
$ tree
.
├── files
│   ├── COPYING
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── max9286.c
│   └── max9286.h
└── kernel-module-max9286_0.1.bb

1 directory, 6 files
```

This is how the recipe actually looks like:

```
$ cat kernel-module-max9286_0.1.bb 
SUMMARY = "Driver for max9286 Deserializer + max96705 Serializer"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=12f884d2ae1ff87c09e5b7ccc2c4ca7e"

inherit module

SRC_URI = "file://Makefile \
           file://max9286.h \
           file://max9286.c \
           file://COPYING \
          "

S = "${WORKDIR}"
FILES_${PN} += "${base_libdir}"

KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD = "max9286"
```

This is how the Makefile looks like:

```
$ cat files/Makefile 
obj-m := max9286.o

SRC := $(shell pwd)

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(SRC)

modules_install:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(SRC) modules_install

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c
    rm -f Module.markers Module.symvers modules.order
    rm -rf .tmp_versions Modules.symvers
```

And these are the actual driver files. Since they are too long, I'm using debian's paste.

max9286.c: https://paste.debian.net/1064976/

max9286.h: https://paste.debian.net/1064977/

I need the driver to be dynamically loadable. Currently the kernel is not able to load the driver dynamically, and it presents the error `max9286: Unknown symbol of_remove_property (err 0)`

I tried manually linking to `drivers/of/base.o` (where `of_remove_property` is defined), which helped but then generated a slightly different error (dependency hell).

Perhaps there's some BitBake variables missing in the recipe, perhaps there's some variables missing in the Makefile, or maybe there's some steps missing in the workflow.

Any tips will be very appreciated.

Comment: Try to only compile the module with 'bitbake -c compile kernel-module-max9286' and check whether you get the warning or not

Comment: I do get ta warning when I use devshell and invoke make manually. 

WARNING: "of_remove_property" [/home/bernardoaraujo/dev/Yocto_RCar_H3_v3.9.0_integration/build.minimal/tmp/work/ttiecu_b-poky-linux/kernel-module-max9286/0.1-r0/max9286.ko] undefined!

Comment: Check wehether of_remove_property is GPL symbol. I mean exported by MODULE_GPL

Comment: This is where of_remove_property is defined https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/horms/renesas-bsp.git/tree/drivers/of

Comment: it's defined in of_private.h, implemented in base.c, and used in dynamic.c and unittest.c

Comment: There's also the relationship between the driver and the device tree, which is not 100% clear for me. https://paste.debian.net/1067777/

Comment: It's not an exported symbol. So you cannot use it in your module